# Executing a background process with system()

Tags: c++, linux, process, background

I tried to execute a process using something like the following:

system("zsh &");

I don't think it works though, because the process doesn't show up. Why doesn't it work? How should it be changed?

Comment: Doesn't `&` imply background, hence it should not show up isn't it? Have you checked jobs running in the background?

Comment: What is the actual command string you are passing to system?  Whatever you pass is given to the system's shell (typically /bin/sh), so you might try testing with `/bin/sh -c "your command &"`.

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of any ampersand to run it in the background, or what system() will do, you're launching an interactive shell.  When you launch an interactive shell, it looks for a console to connect to,  Failing that, it looks for stdin lines to process.  Failing that, it exits.  That's what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Following code works perfectly, using htop I can see that sleep is still running after my app terminates. I don't see how it should be different in your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{ 
   return system("sleep 100 &");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because zsh and all shells bind stdin and it couldn't on background so it crashed. That's also why sleep in background worked.